# Transaction decoding result garbled

Tags: javascript, tendermint

I queried a transaction result using:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/tendermint/tx?hash=0xCDD76608F774BD29CDED2EBD30E94FB66CEF73A9
```

and then fetch the transaction content 'tx' in the returned JSON object.

```
// tx was extracted from the above returned JSON object
let tx = 'AAABF3siZnJvbSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjEwMCwicHVia2V5IjoiOmJhc2U2NDpBNmZUNjFvRnlLNG1HZExnd21xSU5ubE55c1NIQ1BDRm9vb2Jod1BTamY2UCIsInNlcXVlbmNlIjowLCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiI6YmFzZTY0OjFGdmZvZUlLTWlDd1A2NE9IVHd2MHhjeGk3elVBRUNRTkc1NnpnR1lYdkV2UEMvallTcGUvZjVsM0pjRHRNQUl0bHNZMGtrSEZrbHNxTW82Tm9Qa0xBPT0ifSwidG8iOlt7ImFkZHJlc3MiOiJEVkFTNnFzSkxQM3lkUFd0UndkaXNIaXFmVkdtYW1UWVkiLCJhbW91bnQiOjEwMH1dfQAACMs'
```

I decoded it with

```
let value = Buffer.from(tx, 'base64').toString('utf-8')
console.log(value)
```

and then it printed the following result which contains garbled characters at the end:

```
{"from":{"amount":100,"pubkey":":base64:A6fT61oFyK4mGdLgwmqINnlNysSHCPCFooobhwPSjf6P","sequence":0,"signature":":base64:1FvfoeIKMiCwP64OHTwv0xcxi7zUAECQNG56zgGYXvEvPC/jYSpe/f5l3JcDtMAItlsY0kkHFklsqMo6NoPkLA=="},"to":[{"address":"DVAS6qsJLP3ydPWtRwdisHiqfVGmamTYY","amount":100}]�
```

What's the correct way to decode a transaction?

------------- More details ----------------------

I am using Lotion to build my app.
Much thanks to Chandrika's answer.

Comment: How do you encode your transactions?

Comment: Are you using Lotion?

Comment: @Chandrika  Yes, I am using Lotion. Sorry, I didn't realize that the cause of this problem is Lotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Lotion**, you can do as follows to get the decoded transaction.

```
let encodeTx = require('./tx-encoding.js')

let bf = Buffer.from(tx, 'base64')
let txn = encodeTx.decode(bf)
```

Where `tx`: encoded tx you got by querying tendermint.
`txn` will be the required decoded transaction.